# mixing windows authentication with anonymous access

Tags: vb.net, windows-authentication, anonymous-access

I have a web application with windows authentication used for submitting help calls to an organisation.

I have a single folder in this web site with several pages in that folder that I need to be open to anyone - i.e. anonymous access.

With Windows authentication defined in the web.config file to deny anonymous access is what I am trying to achieve impossible?

Thanks.